# How to mock sqlboiler queries in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, sqlboiler

Here I have been trying to find out to mock the sqlboiler(an ORM generator) queries but could not find the way.

Can anyone work around mocking the sqlboiler queries?

Example:

```
func (m *Message) updateDevice(parentID int, data map[string]interface{}) (rows int64, err error) {
    rows, err = automodel.Devices(qm.Where(automodel.DeviceColumns.ParentID+"=?", parentID)).UpdateAll(context.Background(), db.GetMaster(), data)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return rows, err
} 


func GetDeviceByID(ID int) (res *automodel.Device, err error) {
    res, err = automodel.Devices(qm.Where("id=?", ID)).One(context.Background(), db.GetSlave())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return res, nil
}
```

FYI: **automodel** is the package where all generated models are present(like `device.go` for device table). We cannot changes these as these are generated by sqlboiler command and need to generate again if new tables are added or schema change happens to a table.

How do I mock the sqlboiler queries in the above two methods while writing unit tests?

Comment: IMO opinion mock will not be the right way for generated SQL or any SQL queries that are complex. It is possible that you re-generate the code and it will break all your mocks.
I usually set up a real db with docker and run unit tests against it. Its much simpler approach.